# Stop grep from parsing its own output piped to file

Tags: grep

I am using grep like this:
`grep -r "foo" * > output.txt`

However it seems grep is constantly picking up results from `output.txt` which grows indefinitely. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See man grep. Then try this:

```
grep -r "foo" * --exclude=output.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is :

```
grep -r "foo" . > ../output.txt
                  ^^
            parent directory
```